# Exchange Server 2010 ActiveSync SSL Certificate Problem

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-2010, activesync

We have a problem related Exchange Server 2010 Activesync.My problem is;When I connecting to activesync from outside, I am receiving the following error.

```
ExRCA is testing Exchange ActiveSync.
The Exchange ActiveSync test failed.

Test Steps

Attempting to resolve the host name mail.xxxxx.com in DNS.
The host name resolved successfully.

Additional Details
IP addresses returned: xx.0.x3.4
Testing TCP port 443 on host mail.x.com to 
ensure it's listening and open.
The port was opened successfully.
Testing the SSL certificate to make sure it's valid.
The SSL certificate failed one or more certificate validation checks.

Test Steps

Validating the certificate name.
Certificate name validation failed.
Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it

Additional Details
Host name mail.x.com doesn't match any name found 
on the server certificate CN=xxxxxx.
```

Thanks in advance all your help.

Comment: What are the EXACT names in your cert? Is it a standard SSL, wildcard, UC, self signed?

Comment: Do you have a SSL certificate running? is that self signed or actually bought with one of the major SSL companies?
And is webmail working from an external address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DNS name you're connecting to externally (eg mail.x.com) is not one of the names on the SSL cert configured for Exchange (andr for ISA/TMG if thats how you're publishing Exchange) then you'll see that error.

Exchange installs with a self-signed SSL cert but you need to replace that with a proper SAN cert for external access scenarios like this, or you face a nightmare of configuration and support issues.

Here is some guidance for setting up an SSL certificate for Exchange 2010.

http://exchangeserverpro.com/configure-an-ssl-certificate-for-exchange-server-2010